# Twilio not communicating with my xml file stored on amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, twilio

I have a twilio account and am able to make calls. I am also able to use twiML Bins to do some text-to-voice. I however would like to call people hand play the recording stored on my amazon server, my java code is as follows:

```
callParams.put("To", "#number"); 
callParams.put("From", "#number");
callParams.put("Url", "https://myserveraddress/play.xml");
```

The xml code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
  <Play>https://myserveraddress/jazz.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

My mp3 is stored in the same location as my xml. But when I try make a call the twilio debugger tells me:

Error - 11200. HTTP retrieval failure.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: By default Twilio is going to make a POST request to the `Url`, and I'm guessing your web server can't serve a .xml from a POST request.  You can send the `Method` param to tell Twilio to make a GET request instead: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#example-5

Comment: Enabling logging on the bucket would also help confirm what's actually happening.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, this suggestion to add the method parameter worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't take credit, here.  @DevinRader solved this for you, and hopefully will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

By default Twilio is going to make a POST request to the Url, and I'm guessing your web server can't serve a .xml from a POST request. You can send the Method param to tell Twilio to make a GET request instead:

```
callParams.put("To", "#number"); 
callParams.put("From", "#number");
callParams.put("Url", "https://myserveraddress/play.xml");
callParams.put("Method", "GET");
```

Here is a longer sample: http://twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#example-5

Hope that helps.